# C#: Rectangles drawn with DrawRectangle on a non-primary monitor doesn't render top and left borders

Tags: c#, paint, gdi

I have a full screen form and in the handler for the Paint event I am drawing a 2px border around the entire form. I create one of these forms for each screen attached to the computer. For some reason, the top and left borders are not drawing on any non-primary monitors. The form's background covers the entire screen but I can't see to draw (using GDI) on area about 3px down from the top and 3px in from the left of the screen.

My Paint event handler code is below.

```
private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
        {
            int border = 2;
            int startPos = 0;
            // offset used to correctly paint all the way to the right and bottom edges
            int offset = 1;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(startPos, startPos, this.Width - border + offset, this.Height - border + offset);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, border);

            // draw a border 
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Why are you creating a new Graphics Object? There is one in the EventArgs.

Comment: Nice catch. I have updated to use the Graphics object in the PaintEventArgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works Correct.
You should know when you are using `this.Width` or `this.Height`, these values calculating with the frame that surround your form.
For the Height, the height of your form controls added to calculated height.
You can using this code :

```
using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
            {
                int border = 2;
                int startPos = 0;
                // offset used to correctly paint all the way to the right and bottom edges
                int offset = 1;
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(startPos, startPos, this.Width-20, this.Height-40);
                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, border);

                // draw a border 
                g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
            }
```

UPDATE :

If you want to calculating exact size you can use this code :

```
 int width,height;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PictureBox pc = new PictureBox();
        pc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(pc);
        pc.Visible = false;
        width = pc.Width;
        height = pc.Height;
        pc.Dispose();
    }
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {


        using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
        {
            int border = 2;
            int startPos = 0;
            // offset used to correctly paint all the way to the right and bottom edges
            int offset = 1;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(startPos, startPos, width,height);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, border);

            // draw a border 
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't get it. The Graphics Object and the usable Rectangle is in the EventArgs. Why not simply take and use them?